# Cannot resolve symbol 'OnClickListener' in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I am trying to add a button, from the official android developer website, i found to use `View.OnClickListener`, but it shows an error "cannot resolve OnClickListener"  I got two suggestions whether use `OnContextClickListener` or `OnLongClickListener`, please help me, how can i listen for clicks in my application..

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: import android.view.View;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic On Click Listener For A Button

```
    Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1id);
    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
    //Your code here
    }
    });
```